# Messages is delayed by a few seconds, I use writeandflush to write

Tags: java, netty4

When the client is sending me some messages, I deal message and use writeAndFlush to reply to the client, sometimes delaying for a few seconds. What happens? Is it blocked?

Comment: Maybe you can add `childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, Boolean.TRUE)` to your server and client.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's like it's blocked. Wait more than ten seconds, the client will receive messages one after another